# Prove or Disprove an Inequality Raised to the Fifth (UPDATED... Again)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I found this interesting problem:

Given two sequences of whole numbers, $a_1, a_2, a_3 \cdots a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3 \cdots b_n$ with the property that: for all $i$, $a_i + b_i = n-1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i,$ let $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^x$ and $g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^x$.

Given that $f(4) \ge g(4)$ prove or disprove that $f(5) \ge g(5).$

So far, I tried using the info that $f(4) \ge g(4)$ to get: $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^4 - b_i^4 = (a_i - b_i)(a_i + b_i)(a_i^2 + b_i^2) \ge 0.$$

Since $a_i + b_i = n-1$,we can factor it out and divide by $n-1$ to obtain: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)(a_i^2 + b_i^2) \ge 0.$$

Then, letting $a_i^2 + b_i^2 = (a_i+b_i)^2 - 2a_ib_i = (n-1)^2 - 2a_ib_i$, I got: $$(n-1)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i) - 2\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i(a_i - b_i) \ge 0.$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i, \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i) = 0.$ That leaves us with: $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i(a_i - b_i) \le 0.$$

Then, I did something similar with the $f(5) \ge g(5)$ condition. Ultimately, after lots of factoring and manipulation, I am basically left to prove/disprove that: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)a_i^2b_i^2 \ge 3(n-1)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)a_ib_i.$$

Bringing everything over to one side and factoring yields: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - b_i)a_ib_i (a_ib_i -3(n-1)^2) \ge 0.$$

Anyone know how to continue

Comment: Please don't edit your own questions to remove information; this is against Math StackExchange policy. If you keep doing it, I will flag it for the moderators again and it will be locked just like your other question, but I'd rather not create more work for the moderators.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote some simple codes to find a counterexample and I found tons:

1. With $a = [ 34,  1, -19, -39,  14, -13,  43]$ and $b = [-28,   5,  25,  45,  -8,  19, -37]$,
   $$7265877>7115109,\text{ but }99910101<110185881.$$
2. With $a = [ -3,  46, -18,  42,   9, -10, -45]$ and $b = [ 9, -40,  24, -36,  -3  ,16,  51]$,
   $$11811395>11408771,\text{ but }150195321<191229081.$$
3. With $a = [ -8, -70, -22,  42,  56,  78, -54, -26,  40]$ and $b = [ 16,  78,  30, -34, -48, -70,  62,  34, -32]$,
   $$85729632>85706592,\text{ but }1514064576<1859597376.$$

---

Update

Here is a counterexample in $\mathbb N^*$.

```
a = [ 4  7 13  1 14  8 12  7  8 10  3 12  7 13 16  3  8  7]
b = [13 10  4 16  3  9  5 10  9  7 14  5 10  4  1 14  9 10]
234857 >= 234857
3093693 < 3098013
```

---

[The codes.](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/afknst/notebooks/main?filepath=3920189.ipynb)

---

This problem can be described using matrices.

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a positive semidefinite matrix with $\operatorname {tr} A = n(n-1)/2$. Let $B = (n-1)I_n - A$ and we have then
$$\operatorname {tr} A = \operatorname {tr} B.$$
And your proposition is:
$$\operatorname {tr} A^4\ge\operatorname {tr} B^4 \overset{?}\implies \operatorname {tr} A^5\ge\operatorname {tr} B^5,$$
and the answer is no by the counterexample.

Comment: oh wait I forgot to add - the numbers need to be whole #s... so no negative numbers are allowed. do you have any counterexamples that use all whole #s?

Comment: @delhimaths What do you mean by "whole #s"? $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb N^*$, or anything else?

Comment: By whole numbers I mean non-negative integers: $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \cdots \}$. Also, how did you code this problem? What was your general solution iike?

Comment: @delhimaths I just pick $a$ and $b$ randomly, make sure they follow the conditions needed, and then verify if $f(5) \ge g(5)$. What do you mean by a "general solution"? Since a counterexample is all we need to disprove the inequality.

Comment: @delhimaths A simple generalization of your inequality is the [trace inequalities for positive semidefinite matrices](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=Trace+inequality+positive+semidefinite+matrices&btnG=).

Comment: can you send your code? Also, is this: https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1029-242X-2012-62} what you mean by generalization?

Comment: @delhimaths I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks! for the solution using matrices, is there anything about the semidefinite matrices that would automatically tell me that the answer is no? So, after I get this: $$\operatorname {tr} A^4\ge\operatorname {tr} B^4 \overset{?}\implies \operatorname {tr} A^5\ge\operatorname {tr} B^5,$$ can I say that "okay the answer must be no because {insert reasoning}." Or is the only way to do this via counterexample?

Comment: @delhimaths I don't know a direct argument, and I believe a counterexample is the simplest way to disprove the statement.